# How to write text to an output file in a structured, organize manner

Tags: python, python-2.7, text

I'm am trying to to write user input to a .txt file. The code i currently have looks like this:

```
with open('Emp schedule.txt','w') as schedule:
   schedule.write(get_name + "\n"  + str(get_pay_rate) + "\n" + str(get_the_hours))
```

This code just over-writes the previous data every time it is ran. How can i write data to this file without over-writing anything and also do it in a orderly manner with some sort of parameters that i set? Also, any good articles or webpages with information on writing text to a file is appreciated. I've read the python docs already.

Comment: You have to append: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4706520/3336968

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open('Emp schedule.txt','a') as schedule:
```

Use `a` to append to the file.

Or `a+` to open for reading and writing.

You can use [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to write to your file:

```
with open('Emp schedule.txt','a') as schedule:
   schedule.write("{}\n{}\n{}\n".format(get_name,get_pay_rate,get_the_hours))
```

If you have a dict you can use the `**` syntax:

```
pay_dict = {"get_name": "foo","get_pay_rate" : 50,"get_the_hours": 40}

with open('Emp schedule.txt','a') as schedule:
   schedule.write("{get_name}\n{get_pay_rate}\n{get_the_hours}\n".format(**pay_dict))
```

I am not a csv pro but this will write to a  file with the fields delimited by whatever you specify and writes the rows based on  the dict key values of the headers using the [csv module:](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter.writeheader)

```
d = {"Name": "foo","Pay_date" : 50,"Hours": 40}

import csv
with open('Emp schedule.csv','a') as schedule:
   writer= csv.DictWriter(schedule,d,delimiter ="|")
   writer.writeheader() # write header
   writer.writerow(d) # write values
#
```

Comment: ahhh , append mode right? I always forget about this

Comment: Anyway you could add to you answer a bit , some details about outputting in a specific way. According to key words in the file maybe?

Comment: Well i know how to do that, i was thinking more along the lines of i edit the file with some categories then i can output certain things under the category where it belongs

Comment: yeah, or any other method that i could use to make a neat file output